# How to query a Master database using Inner Join links to 2 sub-databases that are identical to each other

Tags: sql-server

I have an Inventory table containing Master file info and 2 Movement History tables (Current Year and Last Year).

I want to use a Query to extract Movements from (say) June LAST Year to March THIS Year in Code, Date sequence.

I am relatively new to SQL and have tried to use the following INNER JOIN structure to do this:

```
SELECT Code, Descrip, Category, MLast.Date, MLast.DocNo, MCurr.Date, MCurr.DocNo
    FROM Stock AS S 
INNER JOIN MoveTrnArc MLast ON MLast.Stockcode = S.Code
    AND MLast.Date >='2011/06/01' AND MLast.Date <='2012/03/31'
INNER JOIN MoveTrn MCurr ON MCurr.Stockcode = S.Code 
    AND MCurr.Date >='2011/06/01' AND MCurr.Date <='2012/03/31'
ORDER BY S.Code
```

This creates a Query Table with the following column structure:

```
Code | Descrip | Category | Date | DocNo | Date | DocNo |
```

...where the data from the LAST Year table appears in the first Date/DocNo columns and the CURRENT Year data appears in the second Date/DocNo columns.

What must I do to the Query to have each Movement in its own row or is there a better, more efficient Query to achieve this?

Also, I need the Movements listed in Code followed by Date sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `union all` instead of `joins`

```
select s.Code , s.Descrip , s.Category , t.Date , t.DocNo  
from 
(
select Stockcode, Date, DocNo from MoveTrnArc 
union all
select Stockcode, Date, DocNo from MoveTrn 
) t join Stock s on s.Code = t.Stockcode
where t.Date >='2011/06/01' AND t.Date <='2012/03/31'
```

beside careful with comparing dates, if Date column is type datetime and includes time you have to change `t.Date <='2012/03/31'` into `t.Date <'2012/04/01'` to include all the rows from 31st of march,
as '2012/03/31' is casted as '2012/03/31 00:00:00.000'

Comment: Sorry. I didn't make myself clear. The 2 Movement tables are identical  to each other (with Stockcode, Date and DocNo fields), but the STOCK table has different fields (Code, Descrip and Category) in it. The matching fields would be the 'Code' field in the STOCK table to the 'Stockcode' field in the 2 Movement tables.